# Exclude current post from loop

Tags: categories, loop

I have a custom post type for accessories. When you view the post it also shows related posts. It looks great, but it also shows the current post within related posts.

Is there a way to exclude the current post from the loop?

```
<div>
    <?php 
    $category = get_the_category(); 
    $model = $category[1]->cat_name;
    $accessory = array('numberposts' => 8, 'offset'=> 1, 'post_type' => 'accessory', 'category_name' => $model, 'order' => 'DESC');
    query_posts( $accessory );
   ?>
      <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
       <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div>
            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'openeye' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            Part Number: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "accessory-part-number", true); ?>
            <?php $desc = get_post_meta($post->ID, "accessory-description", true); ?>
            <p><?php echo utf8_truncate( $desc ); ?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">Learn more about the <?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

For your single-accessory.php template:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php 
      // excludes this post from 'Related posts' in the sidebar
      $GLOBALS['current_id'] = $post->ID; 

      ?>
```

For your sidebar or where you want to show related posts:

```
<?php
        if (is_singular('accessory') ) :
        global $post;
        $categories = get_the_category();
            $exclude = $GLOBALS['current_id'];
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'accessory',
        'post__not_in' => array($exclude),
        'posts_per_page' => -1
                 );

        foreach ($categories as $category) :
        $posts = get_posts($args);

        if(count($posts) > 1) {

                 //do stuff
}
 endforeach; 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you should [never use `query_posts()` for secondary Loops](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

As for excluding current post, it would take something like this in arguments:

```
'post__not_in` => array( get_the_ID() )
```

Comment: Totally make sense, thx! What's odd though is that each returns entirely different results. Is there something else I need to know or do regarding querys?

Comment: @Zach Shallbetter I am not sure what _each_ and how _different_, could you please rephrase that or add examples to original question?

Comment: Sure, WP_Query returns no results. Get_Posts returns one result and of course query_posts returns everything.

Comment: @Zach Shallbetter I have no idea what to think of that. `query_posts()` and `get_posts()` are essentially just calls to `WP_Query`.

Comment: Wild, I'm obviously doing something incorrect then.